# Can I use an ID Token for user authentication?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth, openid, google-openid

I am developing a Cordova app with native Google authentication. I just want to have users create their account and/or login on my app using a "Sign in with Google" button. Nothing more.

After a successful login on the user's device, my client app is given an ID Token. I send this token to my backend for validation using Google's provided library. Everything works great.

Now what? What is the best parctice?

Can I use this ID Token "ad-vitam-eternam"? Can I rely on this token to securely authenticate users on my backend? If so, should I store it in an `httpOnly` cookie client-side?

Google says I should [create a session](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#authuser). As in a PHP session? That's not a very REST thing to do.

Does this mean I will have to make my own tokens after the ID Token validation?

I know a lot of documentation exists, but it's overwhelming and not always easy.

Thank you very much for your clarifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging around, I found [this webpage](https://connect2id.com/learn/openid-connect#cool-id-token-uses). The issued token is valid for an hour, so I'll just use it to make a stateless session.

Answer (score 0):

If you properly verify the ID-token, then you can trust that it is a real token and create a local user based on that. After you get the ID-token you can create a local PHP-session and either store the token in the cookie or in memory.

The ID-token typically have a very short life time, so it is only supposed to be used to create the local user/identity. So there's no real need to store this token in a cookie.

Along with the ID token you might also get an access token. You use this access token to access Google API's if you want to do that.